# View not reflecting updates to database

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am fairly new to PHP and the MVC model and as such, I fear this question may be silly. In any case, I have spent a good day searching for an answer to no avail, perhaps it is because I am not phrasing my question properly.

I am trying to get my View to reflect changes that I have made to the database. These changes are made using forms I submit through the View.

For some context: 
I am building a subscription model for users. On the view, I have radio button form where users submit the plan they'd like to subscribe to: 
Plan 1, Plan 2, Plan 3.

Once they select a plan, I use a Controller Action in order to place the plan into my database column called `plans`.

The code works fine and when I check my database, the `plan` column is updated appropriately.

However, when I come back to the view and refresh, and try to print the column value, the view is not showing the updated value, but rather the previous value.
Refreshing the page does nothing, but after logging out of the user account and logging back in, the view finally reflects the proper value.

My questions:

1. Why is my view not reflecting recent changes to the database?
2. What can I do to make it reflect the changes without having to log out/log in again?

I left out the actual code for the sake of brevity. I will include it if you feel this is not enough information.

Comment: Are you using a MVC framework?

Comment: @noinstance Yes, I am using the Zend framework with MVC.

Comment: Maybe you should try using Ajax to post your form and show the updated data in the same page without reloading.  Also it could be a problem in the function that retrieves data in your controller.

Comment: There's probably some sort of caching mechanism behind your problem. I don't know Zend good enough, but I'd google for that.

Comment: Please mention if you are using any MVC Framework, May be the User object is stored in session and you need to renew the session data in order to see new changes. This happens in Laravel when we make any changes to User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php does not automatically renews the information based on an user changing an option, for that you need to use javascript (or Jquery) Ajax to detect the change (or wait a fixed time), send a new request to the server, retrieve the new information, and update the page

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

in your mvc you'll need to have an ajax method that receives the information and sends back the new information to the client's browser

http://www.phpied.com/ajax-mvc/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I believe this is the right answer. So I'll mark it as such unless I find out otherwise =D!